# No module named flask using virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I am following these steps to learn flask http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world/page/0#comments

I ran this command to create the virtual env:

```
python virtualenv.py flask
```

When I try to start flask using the python.exe file in my project scripts directory, it says

```
No module named flask
```

My PATH is set to the python directory that virtualenv installed.  Why is it not able to find flask?

I initially started with the official Flask quickstart guide and was able to get the webserver to run, but with this virtual env install it is not working.

Comment: Did you also perform the `pip install` commands listed?

Comment: That was the issue.  thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure your virtualenv is activated. Then You check on the `PYTHONPATH` of that virtualenv. Is there a flask package (folder) installed in that directory.

If you unsure whether you have installed flask, just run the following command to see all the packages you have installed `pip list` or `pip show flask`. Do you see flask there? If not you can run `pip install flask`

Comment: I hadn't installed flask in the virtual env directory.  I was thinking flask would would work since I previously installed it in /bin.    For this tutorial I ran this command and it works:
flask/bin/pip install flask==0.9

thank you!

Comment: The primary problem here- and the main problem for most users- is not that the virutalenv is not activated. In fact, the linked tutorial recommends against bothering with this functionality. The problem was that `flask` was not installed in the venv. The accepted answer should be edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem on three Raspberry Pi units at the same time; beat my head against the wall trying to fix it for several hours (reinstall flask via pip, apt and aptitude - no joy).

Instead of:

```
pip install flask
```

I finally tried:

```
pip install Flask
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: After digging and digging, I finally tried this. Not even sure what prompted me to try something with no comments and no votes. I uninstalled `flask` then installed `Flask` and bam... what gives? And thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This error can also appear if you start your Flask python server using `./run.py` or similarly use file associations to start your server.  Then the python command in the association will be used instead of your virtual environment python command.  Use `python run.py` instead.  See how my run.py innocently assumes /usr/bin/python?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# run.py
from app import app
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

Comment: For me, it happens if I set the debug flag to true from the command line. Setting the debug flag programmatically does not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run your script **after** you've activated your virtualenv.  On OS X you'd see `(virtual_env_name)` at the start of each terminal line.  To do this:

`cd` to your virtualenv's directory and type `. bin/activate`

`cd` to the directory containing the `.py` file you want to run at app launch in the browser

Now enter `python file_name.py`, for me the file name was `routes.py` following [this example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework--net-28822)

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also arise if the port is not available.
Try running on different port.

Answer (score 1):

Activate your virtual environment first with

```
source bin/activate envName
```

Then try to run your command again

Comment: I hadn't installed flask in the virtual env.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else helps, check that in your code it is:

```
from flask import Flask
```

I've tried many things before I've noticed my mistake. I had this in my code:

```
from Flask import Flask
```

When I have changed capitalized letter for the module name, i.e. `flask` then everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try below lines :

```
$ python3.7 -m venv env 

$ source env/bin/activate

(env)$ pip install yourpackages

(env)$ python app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows even if you see (virtual_env_name) in the cmd line it is possible that the virtual environment is not completely activated. Deactivate/reactivate and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Python on windows 7. I had same problem No module named flask.

I tried reinstalling python, venv but it did not work.

Finally i run it like this

1. Install venv the usual way
2. go to scripts directory and activate
3. C:\Python34\microb>c:\Python34\microb\fla\scripts\python run.py
4. here microb is my project and fla is venv

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x

```
pip3 install flask
```

Worked fine for me.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

For those of you on Windows who are running into this problem, have activated your venv and flask is installed in the right directory. For me I realized it was looking for flask but the file was called `flask.exe`. I renamed it and it worked perfectly.