# Flask isnt recognized when route updating python flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

Im trying to run `python routes.py` (inside a virtual environment) to get my routes to be updated, but when i run that, i get:

```
  File "routes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

If I then try to install flask like `pip install flask` i get that its INSTALLED already

my **routes.py** looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import EmailUsForm

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = '12345'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    form=EmailUsForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

If I type: `python` then `import Flask` or `from Flask import *` I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Flask'
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: You are using a python executable that doesn't have Flask installed. Install Flask for that executable. If you are using a virtual environment, make sure you installed Flask there.

Comment: Please see updated. Something doesnt seem right

Comment: Do you see Flask if you use `python -m pip list`?

Comment: No, but it thinks its already installed? (in virtualenv). Im running python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have to install Flask in your virtual environment, Since you are using Python3.x, use

```
pip3 install flask
```

Because if you use pip it will be installed for Python2.x by default

Comment: If I do  this with the env enabled, it says: sudo: pip3: command not found

Comment: Then you should first install pip for python 3 by sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: Or you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: I then, installed `flask` via `pip3`, but  if i try to run `python routes.py` it says it cant find `flask`

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`. If i then try to import it via `python` then `from flask import *` or `import flask` it says `ImportError: No module named 'flask'`

Comment: Refer these posts it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414015/no-module-named-flask-using-virtualenv

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask

Comment: Try modifying your wsgi file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188240/importerror-no-module-named-flask

Comment: The `virtualenv` is enabled before i try to run `python routes.py`

Comment: also `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` shows the `flask` directory in there

Comment: If its python 3 then try python3 routes.py