# ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have installed Tensorflow with virtualenv. When I check through terminal it works.

However in Python

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

results in

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Could someone help me with this error?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named flask using virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414015/no-module-named-flask-using-virtualenv)

Answer (score -1):

Have you also activated the virtualenv? Otherwise you're using the python binary available for the system and its modules instead of the virtualenv you created.